# Preventing the address from turning blue when clicking on it in css

Tags: css

I am developing a website.
When I click on a link, it turns blue.
I don't want the color to change and I want all links to retain their original color. I have set all tags in css to transparent, but to no avail.

How do I prevent the link from turning blue using CSS or HTML?

Comment: It is the default anchor tag visited color. If you don't want it then you can change it writing the CSS rule `a:visited{color: black;}` You need to replace the `black` with the initial color of your anchor tag.

Comment: The styling of a link that is activlely being "clicked" is via the [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class

Answer (score 0):

It gets visited color when you click on your logo and text. You can solve this problem by declaring the visited color of the hyperlink.

Example:

```
a:visited {
color: red;
}
```